# How to keep session after storing data in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm new to Laravel. I have created custom Change Password in Laravel 8 using Livewire. But, after succeeded in updating the user password, my session is expired and redirected to login page. So, the question is how to keep the session alive and redirect to the current page?

Here's my code:

ChangeUserPassword.php

```
class ChangeUserPassword extends Component
{
    public $oldPassword;
    public $newPassword;
    public $confirmPassword;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.change-user-password');
    }

    public function changePassword()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'oldPassword' => 'required',
            'newPassword' => ['required', Password::min(8)
            ->letters()
            ->mixedCase()
            ->numbers()
            ->symbols()
            // ->uncompromised()
            ],
            'confirmPassword' => 'required|min:8|same:newPassword'
        ]);

        $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
        if (Hash::check($this->oldPassword, $user->password)) {
            $user->update([
                'password' => Hash::make($this->newPassword),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
            ]);
            $this->emit('showAlert', [
                'msg' => 'Your password has been successfully changed.'
            ]);
            return redirect()->route('user.changepassword');
        } else {
            $this->emit('showAlertError', [
                'msg' => 'Old password does not match.'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

change-user-password.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title ml-2">Change Password</h4>
            <form wire:submit.prevent="changePassword" role="form">
                @csrf
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="oldPassword" class="form-label">Old Password<span style="color: red"> *</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control @error('oldPassword') is-invalid @enderror" wire:model="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" id="oldPassword" type="password" />
                        @error('oldPassword')
                            <small id="helpId" class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="newPassword" class="form-label">New Password<span style="color: red"> *</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control @error('newPassword') is-invalid @enderror" wire:model="newPassword" name="newPassword" id="newPassword" type="password" />
                        @error('newPassword')
                            <small id="helpId" class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="confirmPassword" class="form-label">Confirm Password<span style="color: red"> *</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control @error('confirmPassword') is-invalid @enderror" wire:model="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" type="password" />
                        @error('confirmPassword')
                            <small id="helpId" class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
                            wire:loading.attr="disabled">Save</button>
                        {{-- <div wire:loading>
                            <img style="width: 25px;" src="{{ asset('assets/images/spinner-small.gif') }}" alt="Loading">
                        </div> --}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
</script>
```

Any suggestion would really help. Thanks.

Comment: "user.changepassword"  In this function is there any login route defined because of that it will redirecting to the login route

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh not so sure with what you meant but here's the route definition `Route::get('/user/change-password', ChangeUserPassword::class)->name('user.changepassword')`

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh which function? I have no function named "user.changepassword", it's route naming instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authenticate the user again after updating the password

```
if (Hash::check($this->oldPassword, $user->password)) {
   $user->update([
       'password' => Hash::make($this->newPassword),
       'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
   ]);
   $this->emit('showAlert', [
       'msg' => 'Your password has been successfully changed.'
   ]);
   if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$user->email, 'password'=>$this->newPassword])){
       $request->session()->regenerate();    
       return redirect()->intended('user.changepassword');
   }
} else {
   $this->emit('showAlertError', [
       'msg' => 'Old password does not match.'
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late response. This solution seems to be solving the problem, but in my case it still doesn't work and somehow I need to change the code to `Auth::guard('web')->attempt(...)` to make the code run. Guess I need to ask the dev who handles the auth feature, then. Thanks.

Comment: Does it solve the problem after adding Auth::guard('web') ->attempt...??